# Azure Web App, how to convert image/x-emf to png? [ C# ]

Tags: c#, image, png, azure-web-app-service, metafile

How can I convert emf (image/x-emf) files to png without using "MetaFile class" which seems to not work in Azure Web Apps. It works on self hosted sites.

I don't seem to find any alternative.

Source Code:
https://github.com/KeesCBakker/KeesTalksTech-Utility-Pack/tree/master/KeesTalksTech-Utility-Pack/KeesTalksTech.Utilities/Graphics

Here is someone who seems to have similar error:
[Calling Chart.SaveImage() in Azure WebApp results in GDI+ Exception for ChartImageFormat.EMF only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597724/calling-chart-saveimage-in-azure-webapp-results-in-gdi-exception-for-chartima)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web App runs in sandbox, some GDI+ components do not have permission. Please refer to [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) for more information about Azure Web App sandbox. For this scenario, please try to use cloud service or azure VM.

Comment: Sadly I already know that. So is there a alternative way to convert emf to png?